# mac mono fiddler Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code

Tags: macos, mono, telerik, fiddler

I tried to run Fiddler ( http://www.telerik.com/fiddler ) on my Mac, but there is no native version, so you need to use windows version with Mono Framework.

I downloaded Fiddler from official site, and after installing mono, I 
tried to run Fiddler:

Inside downloaded fiddler folder

***bash-3.2$ mono Fiddler.exe***

But got this stupid error:

Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.

Comment: If you have experienced a problem and found a solution please post the solution as an answer, not as part of the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I searched a little bit, and found a solution: you need to run Fiddler in 32bit mode like this:

```bash
bash-3.2$ mono --arch=32 Fiddler.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed when troubleshooting a staff members machine who was unable to get fiddler running that at the top of debug this was occuring:

```
/Users/user/Downloads/fiddler/FiddlerAttach.applescript:7:87: execution error: /bin/sh: /Users/xx/Downloads/fiddler/attach.sh: Permission denied (126)
```

Basically, double check you have appropriate permissions or run as sudo (which you shouldn't really have to).

Thanks